# R aggregating columns and then filtering

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a #dplyr function that can filter a table when the sum of a column hits a certain value? Ex. if df has 10 rows  and if I add the sum of column1 and it gets to 5 by row 6, rows 7-10 are filtered out?

Comment: `dplyr::filter(df, cumsum(column1) <= 5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
df <- data.frame(a = seq(1:10));

require(dplyr);
df %>%
    filter(cumsum(a) < 8)
#  a
#1 1
#2 2
#3 3
```

Explanation: `cumsum` is your friend here, where in above example you filter rows where the cumulative row sum is `<8`.

Comment: Please leave a comment if you think this doesn't answer the question instead of blindly downvoting.

Comment: Yeah, it's perfectly understandable and answerable. Let's use this space to help rather than police. Voting down without explanation is totally destructive and only helps the down-voter's "cred" here.

Comment: thanks, not sure why my question got voted down... but there are bigger things in life to worry about! Thanks for the solution Maurits Evers!

Comment: No worries @AhmadMobin ; glad to help!